# How can I rotate an object left or right based on the surface angle?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So I'm making a racing game in Unity, and I want you to be able to drive on walls and upside-down. I have everything else working besides the turning. I want to change the direction that the car is turning so that it is relative to the surface angle, but I don't know how to go about that.

Here is a visualisation of the problem I made, since it's kind of hard to explain.

[image: problem visualisation]

Also this is the code that I'm using to turn the car, which does not account for the surface angle.

[image: Current code for turning the car]

Comment: One of the common ways of describing rotation is the axis-angle. Just use the surface normal as the axis. I'm not that familiar with unity, but it should support all the common ways to describe rotations.

Comment: [**Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors)

Comment: In general you shouldn't go through [`eulerAngles`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion-eulerAngles.html) when doing continuous rotation!

Comment: And then you are rotating in **world space** - you rather will want to rotate in **local space**

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is rotate the car body relative to itself rather than relative to the world

if you're using `RigidBody.AddTorque`, instead you would want to use `RigidBody.AddRelativeTorque`

e.g.

```
rigidbody.AddRelativeTorque(0, rotation, 0);
```

or

```
rigidbody.AddRelativeTorque(new Vector3(0, rotation, 0));
```

if you're using `Transform.Rotate` it has a second parameter `relativeTo` which takes in a `Space` enum, basically relative to which space the rotation occurs, you would want to pass `Space.Self` in that

e.g.

```
transform.Rotate(new Vector3(0, rotation, 0), Space.Self);
```

or

```
transform.Rotate(0, rotation, 0, Space.Self);
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice! Everything is working now. I ended up using Transform.Rotate instead of RigidBody.AddRelativeTorque as it feels more responsive, and is just generally more reliable for my game.

Answer (score 1):

You need to divide the Transform body first and then create a up lever based on the surface **Normal** via using Raycast and rotate the main object around it.

I used the [**RaycastPro**](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/physics/raycastpro-214714) plugin here, but you can write the raycast code by yourself.

[image: Root Tree]

```cs
public class RotateAlong : MonoBehaviour
{
    public RaySensor downRay;
    public Transform upAxis;
    public Transform rotateTransform;
    public float turnRate = 4f;

    private float currentY;
    void Update()
    {
        if (downRay.Performed)
        {
            upAxis.up = downRay.Normal;
            currentY += turnRate;
            rotateTransform.localEulerAngles = new Vector3(0, currentY, 0);
        }
    }
}
```

Attach the script on root and define parameters:

[image: Attach]

---

Enjoy the result!

[image: Rotation Gif]

Comment: That's quite neat!